# Taking the last five digits of a number from user input in REACT.jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-input, masking

Basically, I am currently using `this.props.x` (which is the user input) to get information from another page. So `this.props.x` is a number, for example "12345 12345 54321" in three groups of 5 digits. I want to replace the first 10 digits with asterisks and keep the last 5 digits. How do I manipulate `this.props.x` in such a way that I can make this possible?

Thanks.

This is what I've tried.

```
{this.props.x ? (
              <p>
                Card number: <br />
                {"***** *****" + this.props.x}
              </p>
            ) : (
              ""
            )
```

I want the end result to look like 
`***** ***** 54321`

Comment: are you using `connect()` to mount your redux state?

Comment: `is a number, for example "12345 12345 54321"` - looks like string. What have you tried - what is your problem with the implementation of solution?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz nobody's talking about redux including tags

Comment: so it is actually a number not a string. after some research i figured that there is no way to update props.. but I simply want to extract the last 5 digits

Comment: @hunnybuns `figured that there is no way to update props` - not true - you just need to move changing props higher (parent component). Or use state instead.

Comment: @Zydnar I know, but using connect `mapStateToProps`, he can create an updated `X` instead of calculating in every function/place

Comment: @Zydnar That's what I am talking about

Answer (score 2):

if x is a (whole) number then it can't have space and your all 15 digit will be together. In that case you can use something like

```
{"***** *****" + (this.props.x % 100000)}
```

And if it is a string like you mentioned in your question with spaces after every 5 characters then you can use `Array.prototype.slice()`

```
{"***** *****" + (this.props.x.slice(12)}
```

Comment: another cool way to do this would be to use `{"***** *****" + (this.props.x.slice(-5)}` it will grab the last 5 characters for your string

Comment: @Renji mentioned this so I don't want to take credit for that :)

Answer (score 1):

For string use -

```
{this.props.x ? (
          <p>
            Card number: <br />
            {"***** *****" + this.props.x.slice(-5)}
          </p>
        ) : (
          ""
        )
}
```

For number use -

```
{this.props.x ? (
          <p>
            Card number: <br />
            {"***** *****" + this.props.x%100000}
          </p>
        ) : (
          ""
        )
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: typo, two `%%` and a missing `)`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try turning into a string so you can use the substr method.

```
const string = this.props.x.toString()
const lastFive = string.substr(string.length - 5);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple JS:

```js
let str = "12345 12345 54321",
    len = str.length - 1,
    newstr = "",
    i = 0;

while (i != 5) {
    newstr = str[len] + newstr;
    len--; i++;
}

console.log(newstr)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `fill` function too :

```
let arr = "123451234554321".split("");
 arr = arr.fill("*" , 0 , 10).join("");


console.log(res);
```

and the output is :

```
**********54321
```